# Forecasting densities of exchange rates in R

Tags: r, forecasting, density-plot, volatility

This is my first post here so I am not quite sure how to frame a question here but I will try my best
I am trying to forecast densities of daily exchange rates, I have chosen EUR/USD as my currency pair that I'd like to forecast. I am using GARCH models to do the forecast. I have done my coding using "rugarch" package. The code looks like this

```
> ex1 <- as.xts(DEXUSEU) #DEXUSEU is the daily data of exchange rates
> ex2 <- ex1[!is.na(ex1)] 
> lex2 <- 100*log((ex2[2:Nd,])/(ex2[1:(Nd-1),])) #taking log differences, it 
  has 4496 observations



> model1=ugarchspec (variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 
  1), submodel = NULL, external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = 
  FALSE),mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE, 
  archm = FALSE, archpow = 1, arfima = FALSE, external.regressors = NULL, 
  archex = FALSE),distribution.model = "std") #specifying garch model with 
  student t distribution


> modelfit1=ugarchfit(model,data=lex2,out.sample = 2000) #fitting model


> modelroll1=ugarchroll (
  model1, data=lex2, n.ahead = 1, forecast.length = 2000,
  n.start = NULL, refit.every = 50, refit.window = c("rolling"),
  window.size = NULL, solver = "hybrid", fit.control = list(),
  solver.control = list(), calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = 0.01,
  cluster = NULL, keep.coef = TRUE) #doing rolling window forecast

> plot(modelroll1,which=1)
```

Thats how the density forecast looks like, and i am quite sure that something is wrong here, it shouldn't look like this:

[image]

Can anybody please help and tell me what I did wrong. I can provide additional data/information if needed. I am just not sure what else to provide as this is my first post here. Any kind of help would be very much appreciated.